# grepping special characters in R

Tags: r, string

I have a variable named full.path.
And I am checking if the string contained in it is having certain special character or not.

From my code below, I am trying to grep some special character. As the characters are not there, still the output that I get is true.

Could someone explain and help. Thanks in advance.

```
full.path <- "/home/xyz"

#This returns TRUE :(
grepl("[?.,;:'-_+=()!@#$%^&*|~`{}]", full.path)
```

Comment: `grepl("[?.,;:'-_+=()!@#$%^&*|~\`{}]", full.path, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: @RonakShah: the dupe doesn't actually explain the specific issue here. The character class `[]` contains `-`, which creates a range. You have to have `-` as the first char in the character class to avoid creating a range, so `grepl("[-?.,;:'_+=()!@#$%^&*|~\`{}]", full.path)` should work as expected. Use https://regexr.com/ to figure out issues like this.

Comment: @Marius okay..I have reopened the question. I marked it because I thought OP would get expected answer if they escape all the special characters in the regex or add `fixed = TRUE` as explained in the link.

Comment: Yep, I guess it depends whether they want to match literal `[` or not, I assumed they were trying to use a character class and not match `[`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By plugging this regex into https://regexr.com/ I was able to spot the issue: if you have `-` in a character class, you will create a range. The range from `'` to `_` happens to include uppercase letters, so you get spurious matches.

To avoid this behaviour, you can put `-` first in the character class, which is how you signal you want to actually match `-` and not a range:

```
> grepl("[-?.,;:'_+=()!@#$%^&*|~`{}]", full.path)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks @Marius. You understood and provided the correct solution. That link isn't opening though; may be site down. I'll check it later. Thanks again. :)

Comment: There are a few similar sites that explain regular expressions that you enter - you can google "regex explainer" or something to find one that's working for you.